# Which part of speech is this?

Tags: direct-objects, indirect-objects, infinitive-phrases

> "It is obligatory for companies to provide details of their industrial
>   processes."

The sentence above has phrase "obligatory for companies" and phrase "to provide details of their industrial processes". What kind of function does second phrase bear? It is not clear because after verb "be" sentence already has direct object, and after it I see infinitive phrase but to what it is related ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence we see the **For-to-Infinitive construction**.

The For-to-Infinitive construction is a construction in which the infinitive (*to provide* in our sentence) is in predicate relation to a noun in the common case (*companies*) or to a pronoun in the objective case preceded by the preposition *for*. See more examples below:

1. It is necessary for you to do it.
2. The plan was for him to join us.
3. She is anxious for her son to marry this girl.
4. Molecules are too small for you to see with an eye.

Answer (score 1):

"Obligatory for companies" is not a phrase; it's not a constituent.

This is an extraposed infinitive construction where the infinitive clause is moved to the end of the sentence and the subject is realized by a [dummy pronoun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun).

The sentence may be rephrased to:

"For companies to provide details of their industrial processes is obligatory".